# Using the PayPal REST API, how can I cancel a payment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, paypal

Using the PayPal REST API, I cannot seem to figure out how to cancel a payment after a client clicks the "Cancel order and return to website" link. Perhaps in production mode PayPal cancels these payments automatically, but in sandbox mode they seem to stay in the "created" state.

That observation lead me to believe that I need to programmatically cancel each payment upon return to the website's "cancel_url" page. However, I cannot seem to find a cancel function in the PayPal REST API documentation.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

For what it's worth, I'm using the Ruby API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually talked directly with someone from PayPal. The answer was:

> Once a user authorized a sale, the sale has to be executed. It cannot be canceled
>   past beyond that point. So if the user comes back on your return URL, you are
>   simply expected to run an "execute" command on your payment.

This may not directly apply to your case. I think that the only way to "cancel" would be to first "execute", then apply a full "refund". Otherwise, never execute (which I also view as strange because that looks like a potential for security problems. That said, the main problem that could happen is an "execute" on the payment and your company would receive the money that you can then manually refund if necessary...)

Comment: This is weird though.. When you are in the paypal environment (at the moment of approving a payment as a buyer) right underneath the confirm button it says "You're almost done. You will confirm your payment on STORENAME." Suggesting.. you first need to confirm in local store before executing...

Comment: I agree and I first attempt to implement it that way too. Plus, why would we need to run `.../execute` when they could have run it themselves first. I'm not too sure I understand the need for such.

Comment: Yes, was wondering the same... I opened a ticket asking them this again and requesting new API endpoint for their REST API to cancel approved payments. As soon as I get a response I will post it here.

Comment: I got an answer from PayPal (see below) turns out non-executed payments are deleted from their records after three hours. To be save you could delete the payment record from your own DB when the user cancels the payment in your store.

Comment: Do you know how to do it on V2?

Comment: @smartworld-dm, I have not used it, but there is a void. I would try that and see what happens... https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_void

Answer (score 16):

I have been in contact with PayPal's technical support last week and this is what they said:

> If the buyer has completed the work on the PayPal checkout page
>   without cancelling the checkout, then they are redirected back to your
>   site.  If you wish for them to have a cancellation at that point, you
>   can build the Return URL to have a final confirmation (showing final
>   total to be billed).  So at this point the buyer is on your site, but
>   the payment execution has not happened.  If the buyer decides to
>   proceed, then you run the execute command, updating your database with
>   the successful payment details.  If the buyer decides to cancel at
>   that point, you do not run the execute command, and purge the payment
>   ID and the buyer's Payer ID.  There would be no request that you would
>   need to pass to PayPal to cancel what the buyer did on PayPal.   This
>   would be the same type of process done with the Classic APIs using
>   Express Checkout.  Once the buyer gets sent over to PayPal, they
>   choose the funding source and shipping address and get sent back to
>   your site, if they want to cancel the transaction, your site does not
>   send any API call to PayPal to cancel or void the EC token.  It is
>   just not used to collect the payment.

When asked how to handle non-executed payments and if they automatically void non-executed payments after a certain amount of time:

> **Yes, I recommend deleting the Payment ID from your database, so there
>   is no accidental payment.  Our system, by default, will expire the
>   payment approval made by PayPal payers if the payment hasn't been
>   executed within 3 hours.**

Permission has been given by PayPal to post their answer here.

Comment: That makes more sense. It is good to know that we can go in either direction: execute immediately or offer yet another confirmation to the user.

Comment: Yeah. Still weird they don't just have it in their documentation. But we know now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to void the authorization of the payment:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#void-an-authorization

Comment: Authorizations are only used if you want to capture a payment at a later time as defined here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/capture-payment/ and I don't think the question was in link with such payments.

Answer (score 0):

I used paypal api v2, and there is cancel order api.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/?mark=cancel%20order#orders_cancel

Comment: That's a v1 api. Don't tell me I'm expected to call a deprecated api to do this.