# PayPal Checkout: Right way to cancel an approved order

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a server side code that captures orders that are approved by the user. Before capturing the payment I want to double check that the amount payed by the user is the right amount, and if it isn't I want to cancel the order instead of capturing it.

What is the right way to do this? If I just don't capture the order and delete the order-id on my end, is this enough? Or do I have to manually cancel the order and if so how?

The PayPal API had a [Cancel Order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/#orders_cancel) call in the earlier version but they don't anymore. I also saw mixed answers [in another similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20750611/5975598). Some say the payment approval made by the customer will expire if not captured, but some others say approved orders HAVE TO be captured, so I'm confused. There doesn't seem to be a clear answer on their API documentation either.

If I have to capture every approved order then how do I make sure the payment amount is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Orders V2, do nothing. Forget about the id